# Sieve prime generator C++

Tags: c++, primes, iterator

I had some issues with the behavior of the iterator in my prime generator:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a,b;
    int nbr;
    vector<int> t;
    set<int> s;

    // prime generated to b
    b = 10;
    // set 2 -> b.
    for (int i = 2; i != b; i++)
    {
        s.insert(i);
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (s.size() != 0)
    {
        i++;
        cout << "Iteration = " << i << endl;
        t.push_back(*s.begin());
        for (set<int>::iterator it = s.begin() ; it != s.end(); it++)
        {
            cout << "       s  = " << *it << endl;
            if (*it % t.back() == 0) {s.erase(it++);}
            if (it == s.end()) break;
        }
    }
    cout << "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" << endl;
    cout << "affichage des nombres premiers stockés dans le vecteur t" << endl;
    cout << "taille t = " << t.size() << endl;
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = t.begin() ; it != t.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << "t = " << *it << endl;
    }
```

I think erasing an element of `s` in the for loop can be a problem, but the compiler doesn't complain and it seems to work. Is it a problem? I am also happy for a general review.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Eliminate unused variables

Unused variables are a sign of poor quality code, and you don't want to write poor quality code. In this code, `a` and `nbr` are unused.  Your compiler is smart enough to tell you about this if you ask it nicely.

### Avoid single-line `if` constructs

The compiler can handle it just fine, but readers of your code are more likely to be able to correctly interpret the code if you avoid single-line `if`.  So instead of

```
if (*it % t.back() == 0) {s.erase(it++);}
```

use this

```
if (*it % t.back() == 0) {
   s.erase(it++);
}
```

### Be careful when you `erase` an iterator

The standard, in section 23.2.4 says that for an associative container, when you use `erase(it)` where `it` is an iterator:

> erases the element pointed to by q. Returns an iterator pointing to the element immediately following q prior to the element being erased. If no such element exists, returns a.end().

This means that to be safe, your loop should look like this instead:

```
for (auto it = s.begin() ; it != s.end(); )
{
    cout << "       s  = " << *it << '\n';
    if (*it % t.back() == 0) 
        it = s.erase(it);
    else 
        ++it;
}
```

As pointed out by @LokiAstari, this works just fine for associative containers such as `std::set` but a more generic approach would be to use this for the line containing `erase`:

```
        s.erase(it++);
```

This works with `set` but also with other non-associative standard containers, including `vector`.

### Think carefully about signed and unsigned

The code currently uses `int` types for both the `vector` and the `set` but are you looking for negative prime numbers?  If not, it could be that `unsigned` would be a better choice for data type.

### Reconsider container choices

A `std::set` is a sorted associative container.  Since it's usually implemented internally as a tree, it's a relatively computationally expensive container to use consider the fact that all you really need is a list.

### Consider using range-for syntax

The code currently prints the resulting `vector` with this code:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = t.begin() ; it != t.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << "t = " << *it << endl;
}
```

It can be written much more simply with a range-for:

```
for (const auto i : t) {
    cout << "t = " << i << '\n';
}
```

### Don't use `std::endl` if `'\n'` will do

Using `std::endl` emits a `\n` and flushes the stream.  Unless you really need the stream flushed, you can improve the performance of the code by simply emitting `'\n'` instead of using the potentially more computationally costly `std::endl`.

Comment: Your usage of erase is fine. But not all containers return the next element. A more generic approach can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/263958/14065

Comment: @LokiAstari: good point.  The quotation from the standard only applies to *associative* containers such as `set` but not to others such as `vector`.

Comment: @LokiAstari: updated my answer to include that alternative.  Thanks.